# Pandas: Error while loading TSV file with JSON strings in one of the columns

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, parsing

I am trying to load a tsv file which has only two columns:
*property_id* & *photo_urls*

For each *property_id* the *photo_urls* column contains string representation of an
array of json where each json object represents one image (one URL).

[Here](https://pastebin.com/n1kevgfy) (pastbin link) is a small sample of the the tsv file which I am trying to load using Pandas.

```
photos_df = pandas.read_csv('test.tsv')
```

This throws the error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 49 fields in line 4, saw 84
```

I am guessing this is due to two possible reasons:

1. Different *property_id*s have different number of images/URLs/JSON objects
2. The JSON strings are malformed/buggy

I am not able to figure out what is it exactly.

Using `read_csv` with parameter `error_bad_lines=False` is not an option here since I don't want to lose any data.

Sub-question: Even with above two cases why should read_csv throw an error when both the columns are indeed in string formats? How does it know what is wrong inside that string?

Comment: Is this is a situation in which you can pre-process the data? Or a Splunk like tool? If you mapped everything to well-formatted JSON first, then reading would be easy..

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 import pandas as pd
 pd.read_csv('pLurm1w1.txt',delim_whitespace=True)
```

returns

```
    property_id                               photo_urls
0   ff808081469fd6e20146a5af948000ea    [{title":"Balcony","name":"IMG_20131006_120837...
1   ff8080814702d3d10147068359d200cd    NaN
2   ff808081470c645401470fb03f5800a6    [{title":"Bedroom","name":"ff808081470c6454014...
3   ff808081470c6454014715eaa5960281    [{title":"Bedroom","name":"Screenshot_7.jpg","...
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does solve the problem for that particular line but still causes error on further lines. I am editing the question with a link the larger chunk of data. Please see the updated link of the data.